# Unable to access my routes on my VueJS front-end app running on Apache2 server

Tags: vue.js, apache, vue-router, ionic5, custom-error-pages

I am trying to run my VueJs app on ubuntu server using apache2. However, I receive error 404 when try to access any route in the app. I've added my built `/dist` folder in the `/var/www/html/` directory and when I access the public url, it loads the home page. However, when I go to any route, e.g., `http://<public-ip>/device/:id`, then the Apache returns the Not Found page.
[image]

The Vue Router is configured in history mode as follows:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: HomePage,
    },
    {
        path: '/device/:id',
        component: DevicePage
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

And my `.htaccess` file looks like that:

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Additionally, I have also an API backend written on Nodejs (express) that is running on port 8080 of the same server and when the device page is visited, it should request the data from the api. However, first, I will have to somehow configure the app to access the page itself, then will be able to see if the API is accessed successfully.

**EDIT-2:** Well, after the previous edit, I realized that the .htaccess was gone, because I moved delete the `/var/www/html/` content in order to add the new built files and now when I created it, and followed the steps from Hamza Brinsi, it is working properly.

**EDIT:** I tried the solution from Hamza Brinsi, but for some reason it still gives me the 'Not Found' error from Apache. The only issue that I have found was this error: `Invalid command 'MultiViews', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. Thus, I deleted the `MultiViews` property from the `Directory` configuration. Another thing is that I have `../sites-available/000-default.conf` instead of just 'default.conf'. However, I tried also renaming it, but no success with that, too. My `000-default.conf` contains the following:

```json
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my `apache2.conf` can be seen in [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rHgg5FULutUJnpz115EtNOuS9Rb95O7Z/view?usp=share_link), because I decided to not put so huge content in here.